# Removing KML overlay from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a reset button that I want to reset the map (including removing overlays) when clicked.

I've been reading around and apparently the way you remove KML overlays is by;

1. Declaring your kml variable as a global variable

   `var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(null);`
2. These are the lines that cause the kml file to overlay on google maps

```
   var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlFile);
   ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

3. And then call setMap(null) to remove the overlay.

   `ctaLayer.setMap(null);`

However, this does not seem to be working. I don't get any errors so I'm guessing I'm missing something? I'd appreciate any advice on getting this to work.

Comment: layer.setMap(null) is correct, so you must be doing something else wrong. Please post code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the var from in front of the second var ctaLayer  (the one that makes it local to the function).